# How to convert a function in order to use L'Hospital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the limit problem:

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^+}{\left(\ln\left(x - 1\right) + \frac{x^2-1}{(x-1)(x^2+x-2)}\right)}
$$

I know that it has a form of:

$$
\infty + \frac{0}{0}
$$

But How can I manipulate the equation in order to use the L'Hopitals rule? I don't know if you can already use it as is since the rule can only be used if it would give the following indeterminate forms:

$$
\frac{0}{0}{\quad}or{\quad}\frac{\infty}{\infty}
$$

Any help would be gladly appreciated!

Comment: Is the limit from the right?

Comment: First, you have a typo with $z$. Next, as it stands, $\ln(x-1)$ is undefined when $x<1$.

Comment: Hint: The polynomial fraction has $\left(x-1\right)$ on both the top and bottom.

Comment: @Joe yes, sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

As a better alternative

$${\ln(x-1)} + \frac{x^2-1}{(x-1)(x^2+x-2)}={\ln(x-1)} + \frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{(x-1)^2(x+2)}=\\={\ln(x-1)} + \frac{x+1}{(x-1)(x+2)}=\frac1{x-1}\left((x-1)\ln(x-1)+\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right)\\\to \infty\cdot \left(0+\frac32\right)=\infty$$

where we have used that $(x-1)\ln(x-1)\to 0$.

Comment: Actually you cannot use L'Hopital and the limit should be $\infty$.

Comment: @user284331 Yes I just was revising it! I think now it is a more effective way.

Comment: The limit mentioned at the end can be evaluated with the rule viz. $\frac{\ln y}{1/y}\sim\frac{1/y}{-1/y^2}=-y$ with $y:=x-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It is $$\frac{x^2-1}{(x-1)(x^2+x-2)}=\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{(x-1)(x-1)(x+2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

I think that a technique that often works for making an indeterminate form like $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ from a sum/difference is to exponentiate:
$$\lim_{x \to a} e^{f(x)+g(x)} = \lim_{x \to a} e^{f(x)}e^{g(x)}$$
Since that converts the sum to a product. Once you have a product, you can convert that to a fraction by dividing by one of the reciprocals. If $f(x)$ is continuous, then since $e^x$ is continuous, $$\lim_{x \to a} e^{f(x)} = c \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \ln(c)$$ if $c$ is a positive real number, and also

$$\lim_{x \to a} e^{f(x)} = 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = -\infty \text{  and  } \lim_{x \to a} e^{f(x)} = \infty \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \infty$$

For your problem, if we let $y=\frac{1}{x-1}$, then

$$\lim_{x \to 1^+} \left( \ln(x-1) + \frac{x^2-1}{(x-1)(x^2+x-2)}\right) = $$
$$\lim_{x \to 1^+} \left( \ln(x-1) + \frac{x+1}{(x+2)(x-1)}\right) = $$
$$\lim_{y \to \infty} \left( \ln(\frac{1}{y}) + \frac{\frac{1}{y}+2}{(\frac{1}{y}+3)\frac{1}{y}}\right) = $$
$$\lim_{y \to \infty} \left( -\ln(y) + \frac{y+2y^2}{1+3y}\right)$$
To find that limit using L'Hospital's rule, we exponentiate/find the limit/take the log:
$$\lim_{y \to \infty} \left( e^{-\ln(y) + \frac{y+2y^2}{1+3y} }\right)=$$
$$\lim_{y \to \infty} \left( \frac{e^{\frac{y+2y^2}{1+3y} } }{y}\right) $$
You can now use L'Hospital's rule, which will make the denominator equal to 1, and the numerator will still approach infinity, making the limit $+\infty$.